# Why does the cursor on my Macbook Pro 10.13.6 not respond when clicked?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, trackpad, click

The cursor on my MacBook Pro does not respond when clicked. The cursor appears on the screen and I can double click, so I think its a software problem. When I try to restart, it works for a minute but then stops working.

I can see the cursor on the screen and I can feel the trackpad clicking. However, nothing occurs on the screen. I can still type, scroll, and use the touchbar.

Comment: It's not clear what you're referring to.  Cursor *where*?  In web pages?  In a particular app?  What are you expecting the cursor to do?  Can you type?  Please clarify what you're experiencing and what your expected result to be.

Comment: @Allan I edited the question to make it more clear.